# how to set autocomplete to show data from another table in laravel (OneToMany Relationship)

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, autocomplete, eloquent

I have two tables, "patient" and "booking" table. There is a "One to Many" relationship between them. I want to set up a search form in an index_booking page where a user can type a patient_name on it and auto complete show all patient_name from patient table according to WHERE Condition.

This is Booking Model

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

    public function patient()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

This is Patient Model

```
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
    public function booking()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

And i used this code in index page of booking

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
```

I don't know the syntax of code to auto complete. This code working perfectly but to search in booking table, not in the patient table

```
  public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
            $query = $request->get('term','');

            $bookings=Booking::with(['patient' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

           }])->$data=array();
            foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                    $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->patient->id);
            }
            if(count($data))
                 return $data;
            else
                return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
        }
```

In general, This is my BookingController after trying another code for auto complete

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Booking;
    use App\Patient;
    use App\User;
    use Session;
    use DB;
    use Auth;
    use Input;
    class BookingController extends Controller
    {
       public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */

        public function index()
        {

           $search = \Request::get('search');

           $bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
             $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
           })->where('status','=', null)->whereHas('patient', function ($query){
             $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id); 
           })->paginate(10);

           return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);
```

I tried this code to auto-complete but not working.

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $bookings=Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query){
        $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

        })->$data=array();
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }
```

And this is Route

```
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'BookingController@index'));
Route::get('searchajax',array('as'=>'searchajax','uses'=>'BookingController@autoComplete'));
```

Javascript code is

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
    src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
     $("#search_text").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: ...This looks like an error `}])->$data=array();`

Comment: Also, can you show the javascript code you currently have for the autocomplete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to setup search box in Laravel and autocomplete show data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044158/how-to-setup-search-box-in-laravel-and-autocomplete-show-data-from-another-table)

Comment: i added java script code

Comment: Ok, you've mentioned you want to search using your `Patient` model. What fields in your patients table are you trying to search by??

Comment: i want to search in patient_name

Comment: trying to set up a search form where user can type a patient name on it and auto complete show all patient_name from patient table according to WHERE Condition, there is a relationship one to many between patient table and booking table ,and patient_id is foreign key in booking table

Comment: Lastly, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.4.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request)
{
    $patients = Patient::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->where('patient_name', 'like', "%{$request->get('term')}%")
        ->get();

    if ($patients->isEmpty()) {
        return ['value' => 'No Result Found', 'id' => ''];
    }

    return $patients->map(function ($patient) {
        return [
            'id'    => $patient->id,
            'value' => $patient->patient_name,
        ];
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @EsamMohamed Are you definitely logged in? Do you have patients in the database that where the `company_id` is the same as the `Auth::user()->company_id` and patient_name is the same as your search term?

Comment: yes i logged in and have patients and users that have the same company id, if i delete this where condition ('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id) is this will show all patient name ?

Comment: @EsamMohamed Yeah, if you remove that where condition the query will no longer be constrained by it so it should show all patients regardless of the company_id in the patients table.

Comment: i have deleted the condition but problem the same still existing

Comment: @EsamMohamed Have you checked your console for an error?

Comment: Sorry , How to do it ? :)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @EsamMohamed Firstly, refresh the page, then right click on the page, select "inspect", then click on the network tab and then select `XHR`. Try using the auto complete in your form. If you see a request show up in red click on it and then click the preview tab and you'll see the error from your laravel app. If there isn't an error there then near or next to where you clicked Network there will be another called Console (this is where your javascript warning, errors and console.log()'s will appear).

Comment: Firstly i thank you for your patience , i did it and there is no error showing

Comment: @EsamMohamed ...and it was definitely working before when you were using `Booking` instead? Have you copied the code in my answer exactly?

Comment: Yes its working good when using $booking , i copied your answer exactly